# Japanese character not showing properly in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert this JP character in my table. my table has a character set of utf8mb4 but it is still showing as question mark (?)

All other JP characters shows fine except only for this one. Anyone who knows what table setup I might still be missing?

Note: I am using Linux CENTOS 7 . On windows, it is being inserted and displayed correctly , this is really baffling me, I hope someone can help me point to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer to this. Aside from setting tables and database character set to utf8mb4, Below variables needs to be set to utf8mb4.

1. character_set_client
2. character_set_connection
3. character_set_results

Can be done by executing below commands:

```
SET character_set_client = 'utf8mb4'
SET character_set_connection = 'utf8mb4'
SET character_set_results = 'utf8mb4'
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.